# Write, wall, who and mesg

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to set up a server with a lot of users so that (in order of importance):

1. Users cannot obtain ip addresses of other users with `who`, or `last`
2. Users can `write` to each other
3. Users are able to selectively `mesg n` other users, as opposed to simply blocking 
   everyone
4. [optional] Users cannot `wall`

Point 1 is easily solved by a `chmod 660` on `wtmp` and `utmp`, but I don't know how to achieve the other points

The server runs Gentoo Linux

The output of `last` is:

```
last: /var/log/wtmp: Permission denied
```

The output of `w` is:

```
 17:04:45 up 36 days,  2:51,  0 users,  load average: 2.34, 2.96, 2.12
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

Comment: Do the same for 2. You have to do... nothing for 3 and 4.

Comment: except that when I do, for example:
    "write root"
I get
    "write: root is not logged in"

Comment: write requires people to be logged on and have a terminal assigned?  So, is root logged in and do they have a terminal assigned?

Comment: it is, and they are logged in via ssh

Comment: Please show us the output of `w` command. Did you try with another user?

Comment: Added to question

Comment: As a temporary, change the `/var/log/wtmp` permission to the default and try again. There is no reason for _"write: root is not logged in"_ while you said _"root is logged in via ssh"_.

Comment: chmod o+r on utmp fixes point 3, but leaves point 1 open

Comment: What is the difference between `wall` and a simple loop to do a `write` to all users one by one? So why block one and not the other?

Comment: Well, after all allowing to `wall` is not a problem as long as point 4 is respected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `write` command essentially writes to a device file such as `/dev/pts/1`. It seems to consult `utmp` in order to figure out the correspondence between users and ttys. One can work around this by simply listing the contents of `/dev/pts` with `ls -lh /dev/pts` (although it's most probably not needed - see below).

`mesg` doesn't seem to do anything other than setting or removing the group write permission from the tty device file:

```
anthony@laura:~$ who am i
anthony  pts/6        Jun 11 17:06 (:0:S.5)
anthony@laura:~$ mesg
is n
anthony@laura:~$ chmod g+w /dev/pts/6
anthony@laura:~$ mesg
is y
```

The files in `/dev/pts` belong to group `tty`. The `write` command setgids to this group in order to write to them. Therefore, in order to get point (2) working, it should be possible to use ACLs to make `utmp` readable by group `tty`:

```
setfacl -m g:tty:r /var/run/utmp
```

(Changing `utmp` so that its group is `tty` might also work, but who knows what side effects this might have.)

In order to get point (3) working (given that the `/dev/pts` file system does not support ACLs), I believe you would need to modify `write` and implement the functionality in it (for example, read a file "allow_mesg" in the target user's home directory and see if the messaging user is listed in there).

Comment: Thanks :) I knew that point 3 was going to be tricky, but thanks nonetheless for you help. I guess that ACLs are the way to go, provided that write can't leak the ip address from utmp

Comment: `write` is about 300 lines of C. If it shows the ip address anywhere, it won't be hard to change it.

Comment: Now, if I only could use setfacl on /dev/pts/ files it would solve point 3 too! [Modulo some small checks in write]

Answer (score 1):

You could use chroot and lock the users into a custom root directory. By doing this, you could point them to whatever versions of mesg, wall, who, etc.

You could also force them into a shell wrapper, and set your controls there.